# CSV file from a hash Perl

Tags: csv, perl

I'm trying to get csv file from my output.

```
 use Net::Cisco::ISE;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use Text::CSV;

 my $ise = Net::Cisco::ISE->new(hostname=>'hostname', username=>'user', password=>'user');  
 $ise->namespace3;
 $ise->namespace5;

 my $networkdevices = $ise->networkdevices;
 for my $name (keys %{$networkdevices})
    {
       print   Dumper $ise->networkdevices("id" => $networkdevices->{$name}->id);
    }
```

Output:

```
     $VAR1 = bless( {
             'NetworkDeviceGroupList' => {
                                           'NetworkDeviceGroup' => [
                                                                   'Device Type#All Device Types',
                                                                   'IPSEC#Is IPSEC Device#No',
                                                                   'Location#All Locations'
                                                                 ]
                                         },
             'tacacsSettings' => {
                                   'previousSharedSecretExpiry' => '0',
                                   'connectModeOptions' => 'OFF',
                                   'sharedSecret' => '******'
                                 },
             'NetworkDeviceIPList' => {
                                        'NetworkDeviceIP' => {
                                                             'mask' => '24',
                                                             'ipaddress' => '10.66.0.0'
                                                           }
                                      },
             'name' => 'LAB-Distri',
             'coaPort' => '1700',
             'authenticationSettings' => {
                                           'radiusSharedSecret' => '******',
                                           'keyInputFormat' => 'ASCII',
                                           'enableKeyWrap' => 'false',
                                           'networkProtocol' => 'RADIUS'
                                         },
             'profileName' => 'Cisco',
             'id' => '3d21e200-a534-11e3-82cc-00505694f123'
           }, 'Net::Cisco::ISE::NetworkDevice' );
```

This script should give me my selected elements (ipaddress and name) in console but it doesn't work

```
   foreach $name (keys %{$networkdevices}){
   print  
   my $ip = $networkdevices{$name}{'ipaddress'};
   my $name = $networkdevices{$name}{'name'};
   }
```

At the end I Need a csv file with names and ip addresses from devices.

---

Now I use just two methods: `Name` and `NetworkDeviceIPList` (just to clean my output info). Unfortunately in  `Net::Cisco::ISE` there is no method just for `IPs` to get just ips. I can call `NetworkDeviceIPList` and get:

```
 for my $name (keys %{$networkdevices}){
 my $device = $ise->networkdevices("id" => $networkdevices->{$name}->id);
 print Dumper $device->name;
 print Dumper $device->NetworkDeviceIPList;
 }
```

And I have this output:

```
 $VAR1 = 'LAB-W';
 $VAR1 = {
    'NetworkDeviceIP' => {
    'mask' => '32',
    'ipaddress' => '10.66.1.12'
  }
  };
```

But I do not know how to get now from this output csv data with Arrays of names and ips.

Comment: the keys you are using don't match anything in the dump output.

Comment: before reading the code I can say you should always `use strict` and `use warnings`.  You will avoid a LOT of mistakes ;)

Comment: also, you should use 2 `print`, with your current code, only `$ip` will be printed

Comment: I was just thinking this looks suspiciously similar to the output of `XML::Simple`. And sure enough... it is!

Answer (score 2):

The `Dumper` output begins with "*bless*" so you have objects on hand and  thus need to find methods to query them, not directly poke into their hashref.

From [Net::Cisco::ISE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Cisco::ISE) docs <sup>*</sup>

> **networkdevices**
>
> The returned hash contains instances of `Net::Cisco::ISE::NetworkDevice` ...
>   ...
>   When you know the hostname or ID, use the `devices` call with arguments as listed below.

which identifies what class the returned object belong to,  and goes on to give an example

> ```
> my $device = $ise->networkdevices("id","123");
> ```

Then look through [Net::Cisco::ISE::NetworkDevice](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Cisco::ISE::NetworkDevice) for methods to use on `$device`.

So instead of

```
my $ip = $networkdevices{$name}{'ipaddress'}; # etc
```

use `$ise->networkdevices` as above and make further *method calls* on the returned object.  <sup>†</sup>

**Note**

An object is a reference, and normally a hash reference, and one *can* indeed use it as such. However, that is Not Good, it is borne with trouble, and should really never be done.

Every single poke into object internals may eventually crumble the program, and by the nature of that business probably in subtle ways that are difficult to diagnose (discover).

Remember that an important point about a class is to offer an interface to its functionality and shield the internals from any obligation; it encapsulates the implementation so that it is in principle invisible to the user. The internals may change at any point, without any notice, and perhaps in subtle ways.

One should *always* find methods that are provided for that class and only use those.

---

<sup>*</sup> The CPAN page for this seems to have far less detail

<sup>†</sup> Even if you were to retrieve values directly from `$networkdevices`, it is a hashref so it needs to be dereferenced first, `$networkdevices->{...}{...}` where after the first level we may indeed drop the arrow, by a [syntax convenience](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References). (But please don't do this with objects.)